# Wii remote disconnects permanently after 5 minutes

Tags: nintendo-wii, wiimote

I'm facing an issue with my Wii where the controllers can't connnect, and I've tried new controllers and a different Bluetooth receiver, but the problem persists.

There's a pattern: when the Wii has been off for a while and I power it on, there's a 2-minute window during which I can successfully connect the Wii remotes. However, once that timeframe passes, the controllers disconnect, and any attempt to reconnect them is useless. The only workaround is to power off the Wii for some time and then retry.

Any suggestions on what might be causing this?